# How to draw marker and polyline in Google map from database

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I have to make a google map with markers and polylines that is coming from database.I am   able to get the data from the databse in my html page but i can't create marker and the lines between them. 
this is my code...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>A Map of New Zealand</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tooltip {
            background-color:#ffffee;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:10px;
            border:1px #c6c3a5 solid;
        }

        .library-title-line {
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:10px;
            display:block;

        }      
        .library-details-line {
            font-size:10px;
            display:block;
        }      

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        /*This is */
        function getCallbackFunction(req, processData) {

            // Return an anonymous function that listens to the 
            // XMLHttpRequest instance
            return function () {

                // If the request's status is "complete"
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    if (req.status == 200) {

                        // Pass the XML payload of the response to the 
                        // handler function
                        processData(req.responseXML);

                    } else {

                        // An HTTP problem has occurred
                        alert("HTTP error: "+req.status);
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //]]>
    </script>

    <!-- GOOGLE MAPS -->
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAATjlq5e04CjtYAFELAT_MzhQT6W9ahK7sA22kHs_1YSzN-mRedxRoqguZ08pEVBcJstFh9DGuLt__Pw"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[


        var gmarkers = [];


        function getMarker(id) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= gmarkers.length; i++) {
                var marker = gmarkers[i];
                if (marker.id == id) {
                    return marker;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        function load() {
            if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
                var i = 0;
                var baseIcon = new GIcon();
                baseIcon.iconSize=new GSize(12,12);
                baseIcon.shadowSize=new GSize(12,12);
                baseIcon.iconAnchor=new GPoint(6,6);
                baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor=new GPoint(6,6);

                var pinIcon = new GIcon(baseIcon, "http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png", null, null);

                // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
                function createLibraryMarker(point,name,id) {

                    var baseIcon = new GIcon();
                    baseIcon.iconSize=new GSize(20,12);
                    baseIcon.shadowSize=new GSize(20,12);
                    baseIcon.iconAnchor=new GPoint(10,6);
                    baseIcon.infoWindowAnchor=new GPoint(10,0);

                    var icon = new GIcon(baseIcon, "images/smaller-library-icon.gif", null, null);

                    var marker = new GMarker(point,icon);
                    // === store the name so that the tooltip function can use it ===
                    marker.tooltip = '<div class="tooltip">'+name+'</div>';
                    marker.id = id;
                    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        openInfoWindow(marker,"" + id);
                    });
                    gmarkers[i] = marker;

                    i++;
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                }

                var cityMarkers = null;

                function displayCities() {
                    if (cityMarkers == null) {
                        loadCities();
                    } else {
                        displayCityMarkers();
                    }
                }

                function loadCities() {
                    // Read the data from data.xml
                    var request = GXmlHttp.create();
                    request.open("GET", "/maps/LibraryDirectory?method=findAllCities", true);
                    request.onreadystatechange = getCallbackFunction(request, processCityData);
                    request.send(null);
                }

                /**
                 * Process the city list in XML form, store it in cityMarkers, 
                 * and display the markers.
                 */           
                function processCityData(xmlDoc) {
                    cityMarkers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");                      
                    displayCityMarkers();
                }

                function displayCityMarkers() {

                    map.clearOverlays();
                    for (var i = 0; i < cityMarkers.length; i++) {
                        // obtain the attribues of each marker
                        var lat = parseFloat(cityMarkers[i].getElementsByTagName("latitude")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);                            
                        //document.write("///"+lat);
                       var lng = parseFloat(cityMarkers[i].getElementsByTagName("longitude")[0].firstChild.nodeValue);
                        var id = cityMarkers[i].getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                        var label = cityMarkers[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                        // create the marker
                        createCityMarker(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),label,id);


                    }
                }

                function createCityMarker(point,name,id) {

                    var startLatLng= new google.maps.LatLng(28.6100,77.2300);   
                    document.write(point);
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: point, 
                        map: map, 
                        icon: 'http://maps.google.co.uk/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png'
                    });

                    new google.maps.Polyline({
                        path: [startLatLng, point],
                        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        map: map
                    });
                }

                // create the map
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
                     displayCities();

            }

            else {
                alert("Sorry, the Google Maps API is not compatible with this browser");
            }
        }
        //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

I can print the lat-long value but can't set it to markers and draw lines.. please help me..

Comment: Where are you declaring your `map` variable? If it's a local variable to another function, the other functions won't have access to it.

Comment: Google map is coming but there is no marker and lines

Comment: Read my comment again. If `map` is a local variable to another function you're using, the map will load but the other functions (that add markers and lines) won't have access to it.

Comment: see my post i have edited and updated my full code

Comment: As far as I can tell you're not calling `displayCities` which means no data is being loaded.

Comment: see now i have added displayCities() after the map

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39341/discussion-between-user2696569-and-andy)

Comment: This is [Google Maps Javascript API v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference?csw=1) code.  That version of the API was  officially deprecated on May 19, 2010. Quoting "The original deprecation period has been extended from May 19, 2013 until November 19, 2013. As of this date, all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API will work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API before this date."